# Is it possible with Git to commit a file in a specific folder in the repository?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm new with git and I'm trying to use JGit in a java application. I would like to know if Git has a 'commmit of files into a specific directory' or is Git only based on the working tree where files are stored?

For example, let's say I have a file saved in C:/tmp/myfile.docx. Is it possible to tell Git to store it in the repository as /myProject/myfile.docx ?

Thank you :)

Comment: No, what git saves is the state of the working tree.

Comment: Version control systems don't really handle mapping files like that. With Git, you pretty much have to clone the repository as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. Think of your Git repository as a time machine for a tree of directories. You can only add files to git that are inside that directory tree. And don't try to make C:\ a Git repository... :)

So, let's say your Git repository resides at `C:\tmp\myRepo`. To add your file to the repository you'd do this:

1. move `myfile.docx` to `C:\tmp\myRepo`
2. add the file to Git: (using Unix style command line) `cd C:/tmp/myRepo && git add -A`
3. create a commit: `git commit -am "added myfile.docx"`